# How can I check if an element contain certain on Selenium using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, selenium, rspec

I am creating automated test using `selenium-webdriver` with `Ruby`

So I need to check that if my selected element contain a class after clicked.
But I can not find how can I do it on `Ruby` way.

This is my spec file -

```
it 'Desktop Cart open When click Bag icon' do
    desktop_open_cart_button = @driver.find_element(:css, '.profile-container .bag-container .icon-bag')
    sleep 2
    desktop_open_cart_button.click

    cartlist_container = @driver.find_element(:css, '.cartlist-container')
    expect(cartlist_container.has_class?('active')).to be_truthy
    sleep 2
  end
```

Seem like we do not have `has_class?` method.
So how can I check that if my `element` contain a class after clicked?

Thanks~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the class attribute and check if it has the expected class

```
class_attribute = cartlist_container.attribute("class")
expect(class_attribute.include?('active')).to be_truthy
```